# Análise e correção de erros no teste de conexão com DB usando hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Classe para testar conexão do banco com hibernate.

```
package br.drogaria.main;

public class HibernatUtilTeste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //abre sessão
        HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessao().openSession();

        //fecha sessão
        HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessao().close();
    }
}
```

Está dando os erros:

> 1. configuration cannot be resolved   HibernatUtil.java   /Drogaria/src/main/java/br/drogaria/util    line
>      17    Java Problem Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type

A linha é:

```
ServiceRegistry registro = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                              .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
```

> 2. configuration cannot be resolved   HibernatUtil.java   /Drogaria/src/main/java/br/drogaria/util    line
>      18    Java Problem Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type

A linha é:

```
SessionFactory fabricaDeSessao = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registro);
```

> 3. HibernateUtil cannot be resolved   HibernatUtilTeste.java  /Drogaria/src/main/java/br/drogaria/main    line
>      7 Java Problem Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type

A linha é:

```
HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessao().openSession();
```

> 4. The method buildFabricaDeSessao() is undefined for the type HibernatUtil   HibernatUtil.java   /Drogaria/src/main/java/br/drogaria/util    line
>      9 Java Problem Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type

A linha é:

```
private static final SessionFactory fabricaDeSessao = buildFabricaDeSessao();
```

Obs, não entendi porque o projeto não criou a pasta web-in. Vou criar na mão e colocar o web.xml lá, já que também está dando erro por falta deste arquivo.

> A pasta webapp está vazia. Não tem web-inf nem meta-inf. O caminho completo é:

C:\exemploSpring\Drogaria\src\main\webapp
>

Segue a estrutura do web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <!-- Nome da Aplicação -->
    <display-name>Drogaria</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Peguei no link da descrição do vídeo.

Qualquer coisa posto a estrutura do hibernat.cfg.xml e do pom.xml

Comment: @Techies Se você poder me ajudar, fico grato, beleza? Mudei algumas coisas, principalmente no nome dos objetos

Comment: Leia o último erro, ele diz que não encontrou o arquivo `web.xml`. Tu não excluiu ele sem querer?

Comment: Como o @jbueno disse, está faltando o arquivo `web.xml`

Comment: @jbueno o arquivo web.xml está aqui na raiz do projeto. Realmente, vi este erro, mas não deveria está errando neste detalhe.

Comment: Na raiz do projeto que voce diz seria na pasta `WEB-INF` ?

Comment: @jbueno já editei.

Comment: @Techies Não. Está na pasta Drogaria, que é o nome do artefato. Deveria está em web-inf?

Comment: Sim, deveria estar em `Webapp > WEB-INF`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30066/discussion-between-andre-nascimento-and-techies).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vamos lá.

**1º** Seu arquivo `web.xml` está dentro da pasta `webapp`. Crie uma pasta chamada `WEB-INF` e coloque seu `web.xml` dentro dela. Uma outra alternativa é excluir seu arquivo `web.xml` e fazer o seguinte:

Clicar com o botão direito no projeto, ir em `Java EE Tools` e em seguida clicar em: **Generate Deploy Descriptor Stub**. Feito isso voce terá a pasta `WEB-INF` com seu arquivo `web.xml` dentro.

**2º** O nome da sua Classe está escrito errado. Deveria ser `HibernateUtil`, está `HibernatUtil`, ou sejá falta um **e**. Clique na sua Classe aperte `F2` a renomeie para **HibernateUtil**

**3º** O conteúdo da sua Classe também está incorreto, creio que você se esqueceu de algo. Altere o conteúdo da sua Classe `HibernateUtil`:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**4º** Na sua classe de teste, a que abre e fecha a conexão faça o seguinte:

```
public class HibernateUtilTeste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre o conteúdo da Classe `HibernateUtil` pois creio que no vídeo que você assistiu tem uma boa explicação.

Depois de realizar todos esses passos clique com o botão direito em seu projeto, vá em `Maven > Update Project > OK`

**PS**: Uma dica, sempre idente seu código. Pra fazer isso é só usar a combinação `crtl+shift+f`

Comment: vou fazer as mudanças, qualquer coisa lhe digo.

Comment: tudo bem @AndréNascimento